# Pivot rows to columns with id not repeated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data coming in from an external source that I need to pivot into the right columns. Problem is that the id and one more column are not repeated for all the rows. Example data:

```
Rownumber ID     Type             Category Value
1         100   1-Purchase Order  Address  Cedar Rd
2                                 City     Beachwood
3                                 State    Ohio
4                                 Zip      44122
5         300   1-Purchase Order  Address  Rockside Rd
6                                 City     Independence
7                                 State    Ohio
8                                 Zip      44131
9         200   1-Purchase Order  Address  Rockside Rd
10                                City     Independence
11                                State    Ohio
12                                Zip      44131
```

Desired output is

```
Rownumber  ID   Type              Address      City        State  Zip
1         100  1-Purchase Order  Cedar Rd      Beachwood   Ohio   44122
2         300   1-Purchase Order Rockside Rd  Independence Ohio   44122
3         200   1-Purchase Order Rockside Rd  Independence Ohio   44122
```

Please note the ID appears in random order, because of which this code did not work:

```
    select row_number() over (order by min(id)) as rownumber,
           new_id as id,
           max(type) as type,
           max(case when category = 'Address' then value end) as address,
           max(case when category = 'City' then value end) as city,
           max(case when category = 'State' then value end) as state,
           max(case when category = 'Zip' then value end) as zip
    from (select t.*,
                 coalesce(id, max(id) over (order by rownumber)) as new_id
          from t
         ) t
    group by new_id;
```

Comment: How do you tell where one Order starts, and another begins, by `ID` having a non-`NULL` value? I assume the reason you're asking this is because the data is (quite badly) malformed.

Comment: @irshansyed . . . I think the rownumber in the third row of your result set should be "3" and not "2".

Comment: @irshansyed . . . You should accept answers to your questions when you find them helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily fix this code because you don't really need the ids.  You just need a way to define the groups.  So, a cumulative count should do the same thing:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(rownumber)) as rownumber,
       max(id) as id,
       max(type) as type,
       max(case when category = 'Address' then value end) as address,
       max(case when category = 'City' then value end) as city,
       max(case when category = 'State' then value end) as state,
       max(case when category = 'Zip' then value end) as zip
from (select t.*,
             count(id) over (order by rownumber) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

This assigns all `NULL` values to the immediately preceding non-null `id` grouping.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2e6382efbe0df5f782a046e19ce49a41) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Ah this is very clever. I didn't test, but I think `COUNT(id)` with a windows function actually gives you a column of 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2...in the subquery, but then I cannot wrap my head around the primary query. If you `GROUP BY` grp, what does a windows function `ORDER BY` the `min(id)` actually do? For example, when `grp` is 1, min(id) will be 1 (minimum of 1, 2, 3, 4). I need to import the data and try it myself...I'm a bit confused becuase usually I see `PARTITION BY` inside `OVER()`

Comment: Ignoring the `row_number()` part. I think I'm getting the rest: `max(id)` just give you 100 when `grp` is `1`, and `max(type)` gives you `1-Purchase Order`, and the rest essentially pivot the rows to columns.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey . . . I've changed that to `min(rownumber)`, which is more aligned with the OPs intent.  You might find the db<>fiddle helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the fiddle link! I'll experiment with it to see the internals of the query.